# Two HTML page link with using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to connect two HTML pages using Javascript. Also, I get user IP address from the very first page and check that IP address valid or not using JS. If a valid IP address then it wants to pass to the second HTML page.

That second HTML page uses an Iframe tag to use that Ip address. At this time I am writing that code. I want to implement that code for the above condition.

How can I do this? Please help me - thank you.

```
function animatedForm() {
    const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-sign-in-alt");

    arrows.forEach(arrow => {
        arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const input = arrow.previousElementSibling;
            const parent = arrow.parentElement;
            const nextForm = parent.nextElementSibling;

            if(input.type === "text" && validateUser(input)) {
                nextSlide(parent,nextForm);
            }else if(input.type === "password" && validatePswd(input)) {
                nextSlide(parent,nextForm);
            }else if(input.type === "text" && validateIp(input)) {
                window.location.href = "home.html";
            }
        });
    });
}

function validateUser(user) {
    if(user.value == "pi") {
        error("rgb(87, 189, 130)");
        return true;       
    } else {
        console.log("Wrong!");
        error("rgb(189, 87, 87)");
    }
}

function validatePswd(pswd) {
    if(pswd.value == "raspberry") {
        error("rgb(87, 189, 130)");
        return true;      
    } else {
        console.log("not enough characters");
        error("rgb(189, 87, 87)");
    }
}

function validateIp(ip) {
    const ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;

    if (ipformat.test(ip.value) == true) {
        var IP = ip.value;
        localStorage.setItem("ipvalue",IP);

        alert('Valid IP');
        error("rgb(87, 189, 130)");
        return true;         
    } else { 
        alert('Invalid IP');
        error("rgb(189, 87, 87)");
    }
}

function nextSlide(parent, nextForm) {
    parent.classList.add("inactive");
    parent.classList.remove("active");
    nextForm.classList.add("active");
    nextForm.classList.remove("inactive");
}

function error(color) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

animatedForm();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(87, 189, 130);
    transition: background 0.5s ease;
    position: relative; 
}

.field-name,
.field-ip,
.field-password {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;  
}

.field-name i,
.field-ip i,
.field-password i {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.field-name input,
.field-ip input,
.field-password input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
}

div.inactive {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Images/icon/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-log.css">

    <title>Guider Login</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="home.html">
        <div class="field-name">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field-password inactive">
            <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field-ip inactive">
            <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" autocomplete="off" required>
            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="log.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>

<!-- there was a home.html page and it use 

<iframe  src="http://IP:9000/javascript_simple.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen width="100%" height="98%" ></iframe>

I want to repalse IP with user input ip address -->
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage stores data with no expiry date which means you van use it when you move to different html page

you have already used local storage to set the ip in your validateIP function. So simply use localStorage.getItem('ipValue') to get the ip from the first page.

Answer (score 0):

To include an external JavaScript file, we can use the script tag with the attribute src . You've already used the src attribute when using images. The value for the src attribute should be the path to your JavaScript file. This script tag should be included between the  tags in your HTML document.